# Pentaho CDE Bar chart display

Tags: bar-chart, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I am trying to display a simple static Bar Chart in pentaho CDE but while previewing it i am not getting any result.

I am using Pentaho 5.4.0.1.130 version.

my console display.[image]

my chart component panel details

[image]

I checked the Query result in mysql workbench and it is giving me proper result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missed **Height** and **Width** of the chart. Please specify the value of the height and width like below:

```
Eg: Height: 200
    Width: 400
```